# Organize Favorites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks

How do you organize your favorites? My List gets longer and longer and it’s hard to find the entry I’m looking for. So it would be great to be able to sort them acording to their tags or even collect them in user defined folders.

Comment: Nice feature, but I don't think there is a possibility for it yet.

Comment: Seeing that there are a number of people here interested in this feature request, you might get an even wider audience and more admin attention at [metase], which serves as a meta site for issues regarding all of the stackexchange sites, not only for [so] itself. Things work a bit differently here; I still tend to be slightly appalled by the excessive downvoting of suggestions one doesn't approve of, but I don't think your request will be confronted this way.

Comment: @doncherry: Thanks for this advice. I had a look at this meta site an found serval [questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3912/171556) asking for a feature like the one I asked above but it seems there is still no solution in sight … So I don’t think it would be helpful to post it as a new question.

Comment: I put a tiny bounty on it, let's see if it yields any change.

Comment: @doncherry: Good idea thank you!

Comment: [Quoting waffles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/better-favourites-organisation): “the plan is to overhaul this system in the next few months ... ideas welcome, it is on our radar”

Answer (score 10):

Well, we used to be able to search within our favorites, which was extremely helpful, but once we switched to Lucene.NET that went away for arcane (and difficult) technical reasons.

I suggest following up on http://meta.stackoverflow.com as there are several requests to improve favorites handling, but IMHO adding back the ability to search within favorites would be highly desirable at a minimum.